# Drop down list of Android MultiAutoCompleteTextView not scrolling to bottom

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, autocompletetextview

I am unable to get the drop-down list of a MultiAutoCompleteTextView to scroll to the bottom. There is more content than what is showing up, but the list does not advance below a certain point. I can tell that I haven't reached the bottom of the list because the bottom looks to be between two entries. The code to display the drop down is here:

```
            public void onClick(View v) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter("");                 
                v.showDropDown();
            }
        });
```

In main.xml, the element is:

```
<MultiAutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3.0"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/myViewPrompt" />
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting android:layout_height to a hard-coded value seemed to work. This can size the height of the drop-down list correctly to fit all the values, depending on what you enter.